# Regex to collapse whitespace to either a space or a single newline

Tags: c#, regex

I've got some messy text data that I need to clean up.

Each string looks something like the following:

`\r\r     \r\n    \r\nSome interesting      text on line one...\r\n    And line two    \r\n`

And what I'd like to get out the other end is

`Some interesting text on line one\nAnd line two`

Effectively: Collapse any whitespace block containing newlines down to `\n` and collapse all other whitespace blocks to a single space.

I can match whitespace (with or without newlines) but I can't see a way to either preserve *at most* one `\n` or treat it conditionally.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: You have both `\r\n` and `\n` newlines. What do you want to do with them

Comment: If it were me, I'd do it in two passes. In the first pass, change any number of newlines (whether surround by whitespace or not) into a single `\n`. Second pass would remove any repeated whitespace character, replacing it with a single space. (And, when I say "whitespace" here, I mean either _space_ or _tab_, not the Regex whitespace class (which includes newlines))

Comment: I don't know C#, but here's [my 2 cents](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FlmOto): Trim the string, then replace each `\s+` with either `\n` or `[space]` depends on whether it contains a new line or not.

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Flydog57 that approach would keep `\n \n \n` in the beginning of the example string. Also `...\r\n    And` would be collapsed to `...\n And` instead of `...\nAnd`

Comment: I just realize that this is possible with one single regex: [`s/(?<=^|\S)((?=\s*\n))?\s+/${1:+\n: }/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/3wZIc8/1). It's in PCRE though; .NET doesn't support conditional replacement.

Comment: @Flydog57 I don't care about preserving windows-style carriage returns, I just want each whitespace block to result in either a ` ` or a `\n`.

Comment: @gunr2171 Well, the two regexes in isolation are hardly challenging, are they? `var cleanupRegex = new Regex(@"\s+");` and `var cleanupRegex = new Regex(@"(\r\n|\r|\n)+");` It's the combination of the two in varioues sequences that's causing issues and I don't have an attempt at that, because I don't know if it's possible (and if so, how). Hence the question.

Comment: This can definitely be solved without pure regex, so are you asking how to do this only with a single `Regex.Replace()`? With `string.Split()` and a simple regex, this can quickly be done.

Comment: @Xerillio I suppose I've been spoilt by using Python for the past few years but this feels like such a trivially simple problem, I'm somewhat annoyed I haven't been able to come up with a convenient and readable one-liner. If it has to be a few calls, so be it, I can do that..  I will wait a little while to see if anyone has a better suggestion, otherwise I'll go with yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the solution space to not only using regex, the following seems to solve the problem too:

```
var input = "\r\r     \r\n    \r\nSome interesting      text on line one...\r\n    And line two    \r\n";

var whitespaceRex = new Regex("\\s+");
var nonEmptyLines = input.Split(new [] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
    StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(l => whitespaceRex.Replace(l, " "));
var output = string.Join("\n", nonEmptyLines);

// output: "Some interesting text on line one...\nAnd line two"
```